# for loop with file and date listed

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm learning loops and stuff and so now I can do a basic loop but how can I do the for loop and have the file echo'ed next to the output plus the date and time?

So I can both in to separate commands;

```
for i in {1..100}; do 
    cat /var/log/rs-sysmon/resources.log.$i | 
      grep buffers/cach | 
      awk '{t=$3+$4} {u=$3} {print 100*u/t echo " % used"}'
done

for i in {1..100}; 
    ls -lah /var/log/rs-sysmon/resources.log.$i | 
      awk '{print $6,$7,$8, $9}'
```

`$6-9` are the columns for the file name and date/time.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide examples of the input and output you're expecting.

Comment: After breaking up the long lines, I notice your second loop is missing the `do` and `done` keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
for i in {1..100}; do
    p1=`grep buffers/cach /var/log/rs-sysmon/resources.log.$i | awk '{t=$3+$4} {u=$3} {print 100*u/t echo " % used"}'`
    p2=`ls -lah /var/log/rs-sysmon/resources.log.$i | awk '{print $6,$7,$8, $9}'`
    echo "$p1 $p2\n"
done
```

Comment: Thanks leeduhem.. that is exactly what I was looking for, so I can make several loops and have them execute in a particular order using the p reference - I love bash